# how to implement Stream Management through Smack in java?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

How to use XEP 198 (Stream Management) from smack 4.1 using java , Please share some reference.

I am using java code to send message from smack to spark

```
 private static String username = "test";
        private static String password = "test123";

        public static class MessageParrot implements PacketListener {
            private XMPPConnection xmppConnection;

            public MessageParrot(XMPPConnection conn) {
                xmppConnection = conn;
            }

            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message)packet;
                if(message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                    System.out.println("Message from " + fromName + "\n" + message.getBody() + "\n");
                    Message reply = new Message();
                    reply.setTo(fromName);
                    reply.setBody("I am a Java bot. You said: " + message.getBody());
                    xmppConnection.sendPacket(reply);
                }
            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args ) {




            System.out.println("Starting IM client");

            // gtalk requires this or your messages bounce back as errors
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("domain.com", 5222);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                System.out.println("Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                connection.login(username, password);
                System.out.println("Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

                connection.sendPacket(presence);

            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                // XMPPConnection only remember the username if login is succesful
                // so we can''t use connection.getUser() unless we log in correctly
                System.out.println("Failed to log in as " + username);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new MessageParrot(connection), filter);

          /*  if(args.length > 0) {*/
                // google bounces back the default message types, you must use chat
                Message msg = new Message("test2@domain.com", Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody("hi");
              //  msg.addExtension(new DeliveryReceipt(msg.getPacketID()));

               /* XHTMLExtension xhtmlExtension = new XHTMLExtension();
                xhtmlExtension.addBody(
                "<body>My lord, dispatch; read o'er these articles.</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>");
                msg.addExtension(xhtmlExtension);*/


               /* MessageEventManager.addNotificationsRequests(msg, true, true, true, true);
                DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(msg);*/
                connection.sendPacket(msg);


            System.out.println("Press enter to disconnect\n");

            try {
                System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            connection.disconnect();
        }
```

Through this I am able to chat with two client one from smack and other from spark , How to implement here Stream management?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code after creating the connection object

```
 connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
 connection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
```

After this is check out the logs for `<enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' resume='true'/>` which means the client wants to use stream management. The server will respond to this (if supports) `<enabled xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' id='.......' resume='true' max='1'/>` which means the the stream is now enabled

Once done if you checks your logs constantly you will find occurrence of `<r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>`  and `<a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='1'/>` being exchange between client and server.